# Why doesn't "npm run" run my arbitrary package script?

Tags: node.js, npm

I read [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script):

```
npm run-script <command> [-- <args>...]
alias: npm run

Run arbitrary package scripts
This runs an arbitrary command from a package's "scripts" object. 
If no "command" is provided, it will list the available scripts.
```

Ok, I add my *arbitrary package* script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "prestart": "gulp",
    "my_arbitrary_package_script": "node -e '2+2; process.exit(0);'"
  },
```

And now I run it, but `npm` and `node` suddenly throw an error `ERR! missing script`:

```
$ npm run-script my_arbitrary_package_script
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run-script" "my_arbitrary_package_script"
npm ERR! node v5.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12

npm ERR! missing script: my_arbitrary_package_script
```

How does that command work? Why doesn't it run my custom script?

Comment: oh, I assumed the semi-colon is part of his problem, because on Windows command-line semicolon delimits parameters, instead of operations.

Comment: no, it is not a syntax error, it says `ERR! missing script` for some reason

Comment: Stupid question, but are you running this under the same directory as your package.json?

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure `ignore-scripts` is not set to `true` globally.

```
npm config set ignore-scripts false
```